# When braking I hear/feel a clunk at 40km/hr

Tags: noise, braking, sienna

I have a 2004 Toyota Sienna.  When I am braking, I hear a clunk sound. I can feel it as well. Kinda like I have something rolling around in the back, but I don't.  Thing is, this only happens when braking when I get to 40km/hr.  I took it in and they did the brakes for me but it is still happening.  Why only at 40km/hr?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar clunk on a 96 Intrepid. I never did officially find out what it was, but my best guess has always been the transmission disengaging due to the application of the brakes.

Comment: I have similar ifni hard brake. So I experimented. Drive at 60 put in neutral and then hard brake. Did not feel it at all. So concluded I had was you describe and ignore it. For me it happens around 30 km/hr